# I have a written original research (Genetics) from my PhD. My thesis advisor has since retired and my lab has closed (in 2016). How do I publish this?

Tags: publications, phd, thesis, journals, paper-submission

CALLING OUT to the scientific community for your advice:

I have a well-written original article that has yet to be published. I had it drafted (manuscript for submission) along with my Ph.D. thesis and since my lab had closed and my thesis advisor retired, I haven't gotten a chance to publish it. During my Ph.D., I had presented it at various congresses and had even gotten recognized at conferences for the data and people had come up asking when I may be publishing that data. It has been 4-5 years now as I have moved to another opportunity after my Ph.D. and never got around to publish that data.

What are my options now? At this point, I am fine to publish it in any journal. Just want to submit it somewhere for public access as I believe this data may be useful for future research. Also, the topic is specific so there is not a lot of research on that theme these days which is a further reason why I think I should publish this. My lab was the only lab at that time dealing with specific genetic mutations (in mice) so I do think this will still be relevant for the field.

Please help! Any advice where I can send this to? and of course, as I have to do it myself, looking for cost and time effective means. like I already said, I am not worried about the impact factor at this point. Just accessibility and the want for people to get access to my research should there be interest. (also note that since the lab closed, I will not be able to conduct any further studies if reviewers request)...

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking for. Just a suggested venue? Or something more?

Comment: Are you the sole author? Submitting then is easy, otherwise you will need to contact your advisor and any other authors. Publication charges might be trickier, but not all journals have them (or they can be waived). Of course, if in a field that uses arxiv or something similar you can just post it there once you have an account.

Comment: Another consideration is that you may need to update the literature review, but if there isn't too much research on the topic these days that shouldn't be too much work.

Comment: You publish it by submitting it to a journal and getting it accepted if it is good enough. As @Buffy said, what else do you need to know exactly?

Comment: @JonCuster You'd be surprised - I vividly remember myself sitting there, in front of the finished article which looked just like any article from a journal X and not knowing what to do next. Before you do a submission on your own, it is a completely opaque black box turning written articles into publications - all that knowledge about journal workflows and whatnot doesn't do anything until you walk that path for the first time and realize there's no more to it than what you already know. At least this was the case for me and I know I am not alone in that.

Comment: @Lodinn I mean, OP has a PhD and presumably has figured that part out by now.

Comment: @Scientist Presumably though, you do need to get in touch with someone about whether *you* have permission to share the data.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Eh, one could hope, but that is not a given (at least I know of a handful of examples of people graduating with all of the articles written by a supervisor, and a few more of articles (co-)authored by them but submitted by a supervisor). A PhD is supposed to make one an independent researcher, but does not always succeed in that.